# Getting argument list in a Boost:Python function

Tags: python, boost, python-2.7, boost-python, cpython

In CPython we can get the argument list of a function by following methods.
function name is 'aMethod'

```
import inspect
inspect.getargspec(aMethod)
```

or

```
aMethod.func_code.co_varnames
```

How can I achieve the same thing for a Boost:Python function? I get the following error when I use these methods in for those.

for the first method
TypeError:  is not a Python function

for the second method
AttributeError: 'aMethod' object has no attribute 'func_code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a Python attribute on a [`boost::python::object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html), use the `attr` member function.  For example:

```
aMethod.func_code.co_varnames
```

would become

```
aMethod.attr("func_code").attr("co_varnames")
```

---

Here is a complete example.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/stl_iterator.hpp>

void print_varnames(boost::python::object fn)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  typedef python::stl_input_iterator<std::string> iterator;

  std::vector<std::string> var_names(
    iterator(fn.attr("func_code").attr("co_varnames")),
    iterator());

  BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string& varname, var_names)
    std::cout << varname << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  def("print_varnames", &print_varnames);
}
```

Usage:

```python
>>> def test1(a,b,c): pass
... 
>>> def test2(spam, eggs): pass
... 
>>> def test3(): pass
... 
>>> from example import print_varnames
>>> print_varnames(test1)
a
b
c
>>> print_varnames(test2)
spam
eggs
>>> print_varnames(test3)
>>>
```

Comment: error C2039: 'stl_input_iterator' : is not a member of 'boost::python'. 
 I get this error while building.
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 32-bit, Python 2.7 and Boost 1.47.

Comment: after importing stl_iterator it works, but gives the same error while getting the argument list using that method.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. there was an issue in the function in which I used to get arguments. The problem in this works only when Python is is run on command prompt. But anyways, it works now :D.
Thnaks

Comment: @maheshakya: I've made the edit since there is no harm in it.  As of 2 years ago, the [convenience header file](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/72746) on the trunk (r72746) includes `stl_iterator`.  However, it does not appear to be merged into the release branches.

Answer (score 0):

Careful: This approach will print out *all* variables in a function, not just its parameters.  To wit:

```
def test4(a, b):
    c = a + b

>>> test4.__code__.co_varnames
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

If you really need just the function parameters, just use the `inspect` module:

```
// given f as callable boost::python::object
auto inspect = python::import("inspect");
auto argspec = inspect.attr("getargspec")(f);
// returns args in argspec[0] (and varargs in [1], keywords in [2], and defaults in [3]).
```